# Toc spacing in KOMA

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

I am currently using the class `scrreprt` which means I need a solution compatible to KOMA. I have the following ToC:

[image: picture]

Now I want to reduce the space between the chapters. Another thing I want is that the dots should reach the page number. Is this possible without `tocloft`?

```
\documentclass[
12pt, 
numbers=noenddot, 
listof=entryprefix
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} 

\usepackage{lmodern}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} 

\usepackage[tmargin=3cm, lmargin=3cm, rmargin=2.5cm, bmargin=2cm,      headheight=27.18335pt,footnotesep=2\baselineskip]{geometry}


\begin{document}


\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chap 1}
\section{Sec 1}
\subsection{Subsec 1}
\section{Sec 2}
\section{Sec 3}
\chapter{Chap 2}
\chapter{Chap 3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us help you and add a minimal working example  [(MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` (including only relevant packages) that still illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem will be much easier when we see compilable code, and you'll be more likely to receive help this way.

Comment: You should **not** use `tocloft` and `KOMA` classes/packages together. Use one of them, not both!

Comment: For the dots issue, try `\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{0.5em}
\makeatother` if you don't want to use any new packages? But it's not optimal I think.

Comment: Sorry, I added a MWE. The example for the dots works more or less :) thanks for this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the distance before the entries using option `tocbeforeskip` of command `\RedeclareSectionCommand`.

You can change the width of the page number column redefining `\@pnumwidth`.

```
\documentclass[
12pt, 
numbers=noenddot, 
listof=entryprefix
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} 

\usepackage{lmodern}

%\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% You should not switch of paragraph indention
                            % without selecting another paragraph formatting,
                            % e.g., using option parskip.

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} 

\usepackage[tmargin=3cm, lmargin=3cm, rmargin=2.5cm, bmargin=2cm,      headheight=27.18335pt,footnotesep=2\baselineskip]{geometry}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocbeforeskip=1ex plus 1pt minus 1pt]{chapter}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@pnumwidth}{1em}% Width of the page number column in the table
                                % of contents.
\makeatother


\begin{document}


\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chap 1}
\section{Sec 1}
\subsection{Subsec 1}
\section{Sec 2}
\section{Sec 3}
\chapter{Chap 2}
\chapter{Chap 3}

\end{document}
```

results in

[image]

instead of

[image]

If you want, you can set both to 0, but I don't like the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That works really good. Is there a similar command for the lof and lot?

Comment: @GR_ CHeck the manual for `listof=nochaptergap`

Comment: In the documentation, Markus Kohm states in a similar example "Note that the glue also switches the algebraic sign before becoming a skip, if the
value is negative" (chapter 21: additional information about the main classes and scrextend). Wouldn't be this valid here too?

Comment: @Twonky: No, because the note is about negative values of `beforeskip` and `afterskip` not about positive values of `tocbeforeskip`. And with KOMA-Script 3.26a I would recommend to not longer use the sign dependency of `beforeskip` and `afterskip` but switch to `afterindent=false` and `runin=false` etc. to explicitly (de)activate indentation of the first paragraph or run-in headings.